# Change Arbitrary property given as parameter to function

Tags: python, function, parameters, properties

for a project I'm trying to recreate a system that was written out on Paper. It Involves a ranking order from F through A, multiple stats ranked on that scale as properties of an Object, and a Function that is intended to take one of those stats as input, and raise or lower it by a certain amount.
The issue is I need the function to change the properties, inside of the function itself.
To attempt this, I first made a list with the ranking

```
stat_ranking = [None,"F","E","D","C","B","A",None]
```

Then created the Class

```
class char():
  def __init__(self,X,Y,Z):
    self.X = X
    self.Y = Y
    self.Z = Z
  def stat_change(self,stat,amount):
    for i in range(abs(amount)):
      if amount > 0:
        newValue = stat_ranking[stat_ranking.index(stat)+1]
      else:
        newValue = stat_ranking[stat_ranking.index(stat)-1]
      if newValue != None:
        stat = newValue
```

And created an object in it.
`box = char("D","C","A")`

What I want to happen is for example, I could give it the input:
`box.stat_change(box.X,2)`
And it would repeat the amount of times (in this case 2). It would then move the stat given (in this case X which is "E") Over 1 (to "C" (or "E" if negative)), then setting the property to that amount. The Nones are to prevent it from going out of Range.
However, it appears to create a new "stat" local variable and give it the value that I want to be put in the property.
I've tried returning "stat" and setting the property to the output, which works, but that requires it to be outside of the function, I don't know how I would have it changed the property given inside of the function. This doesn't work for the assignment given.

Thank you.

Comment: You could e. g. give the function a "statname" parameter instead of "stat" which would be a string "X", "Y" or "Z" and use "getattr(self, statname)" and "setattr(...)" for retrieving and setting of the object attribute.

Comment: That worked perfectly for what I needed, Thank you!